# How can I import a ttf file as Font in Unity at runtime?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mono

I'm working in a project and I need to load font, cuz these fonts can be customizable

I'm trying methods like just Font class ctor, trying using TMPro but I can't find some info about that and looks like nobody needed it never before.

Comment: Can't you make an assetbundle or addressable and load it?

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.Load.html

Answer (score 0):

To use TTF file you have to first convert it to Unity Asset font. You can Do this by First **Window > Text Mesh Pro > Unity Asset Font**

[Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/reJK3.png)

[Text Mesh Pro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WFIfE.png)

**Select The Font You want to use in Source Font File**

[Select The Font](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSc6p.png)

**Then, Click On Generate Font Atlas**

[Generate font](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SEGv9.png)

**Click On Save As And Now You Can use Your Font**

[Save As](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZO0Oh.png)

[Text font changed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQvfV.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your answer. Please provide more details about your solution. Code snippets, high quality descriptions, or any relevant information would be great. Clear and concise answers are more helpful and easier to understand for everyone. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77045362/edit) your answer with specifics to raise the quality of your answer. For more information: [How To: Write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Happy coding!